# Does anyone have recommendations on photo tours to Cuba?

Tags: travel, service-recommendation, locations

Does anyone have recommendations or comments on photo tours to Cuba? There are quite a few out there now with minimal post-tour feedback. I'll be traveling from the US (but not a US citizen).

Comment: Have you checked on the travel stackexchange site?  Guessing you'd be more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a particular recommendation with respect to photo tours but I have been a few times and **Cuba is gorgeous!**  Get away from the tourist resorts and you will be in a photographer's dream.  The old city architecture in any of the bigger cities is stunning and largely in a state of disrepair which makes it real. (Like Prague before the fall of communism kind of real - capture it while you can) They still do drive a lot of those old American cars so you can frame unbelievable urban still-life photos. Hit the mountains and the mountain villages - a whole different world all together. I am referring to the mountains near Cienfuegos which is where I was and i was blown away by the beauty and the vistas, waterfalls and caves.
The problem with Cuba is that there is so much to photograph. Personally I would not want to be constrained to the timelines of a tour. Rent a car instead. Cuba is safe and the people are very friendly. You could scout some locations before the trip on Google earth (high resolution imagery coverage is good) and prepare your own tour. Know what you roughly want to photograph and then it's just a matter of fine-tuning the locations and timing the golden hour. (Assuming you want to shoot landscape)

Comment: I would particulary recommend "Viñales" valley in "Pinar del Rio" province for landscape pictures, and if possible, underwater photography in the northen shore. The coral reef there is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a tour group called 'Cuban Photo Tours' that was really good, they spend time in Havana but also do excursions out to other areas. They have a local guide who is really helpful, and also a really good instructor. Their website is: http://www.cubanphototours.com/